# Signal-to-noise-ratio, Fisher information and and "estimability"

Tags: estimation, references, terminology, fisher-information, point-estimation

Given a parametric statistical model, is it common to study the quantity
$$ Q_{\theta} = \theta^2 I_{\theta} \, ,$$
where $I_{\theta}$ is the Fisher information? (I focus on a single parameter for simplicity.)

The reason I am asking is that I am familiar with [these notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2981.pdf) on *quantum* parameter estimation (this is not important for the discussion). In Sec. 3 (p. 7) the author writes down this inequality
$$
R_{\theta} = \frac{\theta^2}{\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta})} \leq Q_{\theta}
$$
deriving from the Cramér-Rao lower bound for $\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\theta})$.

Is $R_{\theta}$ usually called the "signal-to-noise ratio" in statistics?
Furthermore he also introduces the term "estimability of a parameter" speaking about $Q_{\theta}$. Is this standard nomenclature?

I wanted to find out more about these topics, but I could not find good references.
Apparently these terms are used with different meanings in statistics.
So I am asking to be pointed to the correct references.

Coming from physics I think about the Fisher information (and the variance) as a [dimensional quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) (i.e. with units), since the parameter to be estimated usually has a physical dimension.
One nice thing about the quantity $Q_{\theta}$ is that it is dimensionless.

Please forgive me if my terminology is not exact, I am a physicist and I don't have a proper background in statistics.

Comment: Did you find any sources for this. I am trying to find a quantitative relation between SNR and Fisher Information.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela unfortunately I haven't found any classical statistics material on this topic of "estimability of a parameter".
I wonder if my question was formulated in a way that makes it unclear and/or uninteresting for the statisticians who visit this StackExchange.

Comment: Giving a thought to it, I realize that R is rightly stated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio#cite_note-5 (Check alternate definitions) SNR is defined as ratio of mean and standard deviation squared. So for an unbiased estimator the mean is equal to the parameter itself i.e. theta. and standard deviation squared is variance.

Comment: Apart from that you know how the inequality is derived between R and Q.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela thanks, I had missed that section on the Wikipedia article. I was not doubting it's a well defined quantity. But it seems that it is mostly considered in applied fields (e.g. astronomy / imaging), while I was curious to know if statisticians ever think about "estimability of parameters" and if there are some more fundamental geometric / information theoretical concepts behind this idea.